# Material UI Advanced Button - Text Alignment for Small Screensizes

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

React / Material-UI Novice here. I am trying to configure a set of buttons inside my app Bar that have a background picture to make it look a little cleaner. I have used a lot of code from examples online (shock) and got it to a place where i am happy with how it has formatted on a full size view (md++). However, when i downsize it to a small breakpoint though, the button image then stack instead (which is what i want) but i lose my text to the left. I have tried shifting to the right in many different ways but i dont think thats the right way to do it, is there something i am missing in making the text flex, i want the text to be in the middle?

```
import React from 'react'

import { AppBar, Toolbar } from "@mui/material";
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles'
import Button from '@mui/material/Button'
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack'
import ButtonBase from '@mui/material/ButtonBase';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({

    button: {
        ...theme.typography.mainmenu,
        borderRadius: "40px",
        marginLeft: "1px",
        height: "45px",
        "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary
        }
    },

}))

const images = [
    {
        url: '/assets/breakfastMenu.jpg',
        title: 'Breakfast',
        width: '33.33%',
    },
    {
        url: '/assets/steak.jpg',
        title: 'Mains',
        width: '33.33%',
    },
    {
        url: '/assets/desserts.jpg',
        title: 'Desserts',
        width: '33.33%',
    },
];
const Image = styled('span')(({ theme }) => ({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    color: theme.palette.common.primary,
}));

const ImageButton = styled(ButtonBase)(({ theme }) => ({
    position: 'relative',
    height: 150,
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
        width: '100% !important', // Overrides inline-style
        height: 100,
    },
    '&:hover, &.Mui-focusVisible': {
        zIndex: 1,
        '& .MuiImageBackdrop-root': {
            opacity: 0.15,
        },
        '& .MuiImageMarked-root': {
            opacity: 0,
        },
        '& .MuiTypography-root': {
            border: '4px solid currentColor',
        },
    },
}));

const ImageSrc = styled('span')({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    backgroundPosition: 'center 40%',
});
const ImageBackdrop = styled('span')(({ theme }) => ({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.black,
    opacity: 0.4,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('opacity'),
}));

const ImageMarked = styled('span')(({ theme }) => ({
    height: 3,
    width: 18,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: -2,
    left: 'calc(50% - 9px)',
    transition: theme.transitions.create('opacity'),
}));

const Header = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (<React.Fragment><AppBar position="sticky" className={classes.appBar}>
        <Toolbar disableGutters className={classes.mainToolbar} sx={{ justifyContent: "center" }}>
            <Stack direction="row" justifyContent="space-between" alignItems="center" spacing={10}>
                {/*  <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" className={classes.button}>Breakfast</Button>
                <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" className={classes.button}>Mains</Button>
<Button variant="contained" color="secondary" className={classes.button}>Desserts</Button> */}
                <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap', minWidth: 900, width: '100%' }}>
                    {images.map((image) => (
                        <ImageButton
                            focusRipple
                            key={image.title}
                            style={{
                                width: image.width,
                            }}
                        >
                            <ImageSrc style={{
                                backgroundImage: `url(${image.url})`
                            }} />
                            <ImageBackdrop className="MuiImageBackdrop-root" />
                            <Image>
                                <Typography
                                    component="span"
                                    variant="subtitle1"
                                    color="white"
                                    fontWeight="bold"

                                    sx={{
                                        position: 'relative',
                                        p: "7em",
                                        pt: "2em",
                                        pb: (theme) => `calc(${theme.spacing(1)} + 6px)`,
                                    }}
                                >
                                    {image.title}
                                    <ImageMarked className="MuiImageMarked-root" />
                                </Typography>
                            </Image>
                        </ImageButton>
                    ))}
                </Box>
            </Stack>
        </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>

    </React.Fragment >
    )
}

export default Header
```

Answer (score 0):

I have moved on from this, but in case anybody finds it, using MUI i completely adapted my application by using:

```
import useMediaQuery from '@mui/material/useMediaQuery'
```

and some example like:

```
const matches = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("md"))
```

to control when the application changes its styles